# Different Approach to Hiding image in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm responsible for developing an approach/algorithm to hide image on the trigger. But hiding should be in such a way that it would be hard for developers to do "inspect code" and change certain javascript variables or setting some condition true. So `visibility:hidden` is a no for sure because it's easy to get rid of it through "inspect code".

Only viable option I can think of is injecting image code () through JQuery which would make it quite work for someone to trigger it manually (I believe). But not sure if it's good enough.

What kind of an approach I can implement? Every opinion counts. Thank you.

To clarify: there are 2 images. each button hover will trigger visibility of one of the images. And the goal is to forbid the user from viewing both of them simultaneously. And they may avoid this by changing script conditions and variables. How to prevent that happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like the below to detect when someone uses inspect element to completely hide the content they're trying to change.

```
var currentHtmlContent;
var element = new Image();
var elementWithHiddenContent = document.querySelector("#element-to-hide");
var innerHtml = elementWithHiddenContent.innerHTML;
element.__defineGetter__("id", function() {
    currentHtmlContent= "";
});
setInterval(function() {
   currentHtmlContent= innerHtml;
   console.log(element);
   console.clear(); 
   elementWithHiddenContent.innerHTML = currentHtmlContent;
}, 1000);
```

It will then show the content when they stop inspecting.

Comment: will give it a try and will notify. But the idea is quite good and simple. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, let us know how you get on

Comment: Sorry but this didn't work in my case. Not sure if i failed to define the getter.

Comment: I have created you a Fiddle to take a look at: https://jsfiddle.net/zs5a7b92/ seems to work fine.

Comment: Appreciated the effort, clean code. Unfortunately doesn't work for Firefox. Anywho, i decided to use a github library called "devtools-detect". It's pretty neat ! Despite all that, thanks for leading the way. I found that library thanks to your answer. And i believe it counts as the right answer.

Comment: No problem, glad it inspired you to find something more suitable to your needs :)